# Meaning of "as anything but ______" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, understanding

I have found a GRE question from official ETS practice book for verbal. I am kind of stuck with the type of the question asked in GRE that is posted here.

> The media once portrayed the governor as anything but ineffective; they now, however, make her out to be the epitome of ________________.
>
> A) fecklessness
>
> B) brilliance
>
> C) dynamism
>
> D) egoism
>
> E) punctiliousness

Can you explain the meaning and context?

Comment: See also: http://www.tcyonline.com/blog/gre-verbal-killer-strategy-for-a-daunting-sentence-structure

Comment: Ajay: I strongly recommend you read [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) on meta.

Comment: pitiful it is. We, at times, keep on upvoting very very basic questions here. And ***genuine*** question like this gets closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good question.

Be cautious when you see `'anything but'` **in such context**. There could be two possibilities.

> 'anything but [a positive word]'

and

> 'anything but [a negative word]'

The meaning of the sentence depends on the usage of 'positive' or 'negative' words after the format `anything but`. The key to understand this is, if it uses a 'negative word', take the sentence positively. And vise versa...

Here, it uses a negative word `ineffective`. This means, the sentence is positive. The media portrayed the person something 'positive' (in this case-effective).

The latter part of the sentence asks us to come up with **opposite** to what it has been said. Because it uses *"...they now, however,..."*

This means you need to come up with a 'negative'. Now, she is an epitome (example) of something 'negative.

Said that, [brilliance](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=brilliance), [dynamism](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=dynamism), [punctiliousness](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=punctiliousness%20), being positive words, are out.

Ego cannot come because **previously** the did not specify that.

So, what is left? `fecklessness`

That's the answer!

Check out the meaning and you'll confirm that

> [fecklessness](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=fecklessness):   Worthlessness due to being feeble and ***ineffectual***

---

I had no idea for the answer mentioned elsewhere. This is [the source](http://www.tcyonline.com/blog/gre-verbal-killer-strategy-for-a-daunting-sentence-structure) though (Damkerng's comment)

Comment: Thanks Ajay, but a little suggestion -wait for others to answer. They may come up with better one, especially natives! :) I learn a lot from them. And thanks again, it gave me a chance to ponder over such a nice topic! :)

Comment: @MaulikV Please read http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing. It'd be amazing if you could've come up with almost exactly the same explanation as the one given in http://www.tcyonline.com/blog/gre-verbal-killer-strategy-for-a-daunting-sentence-structure, which was dated October 2014. But if you didn't, I trust your discretion and believe that you know what you should do with this answer.

Comment: This is a naturally written answer. It is in the flow as if I'm telling someone. I generally don't search for 'answers'. I refer dictionaries and use my own volition to explain it the way an Indian understands. @DamkerngT. I just saw the link you provided, and looking at it, this doubt is obvious. But then, you 'know' me for past one year. And yes, I have learned the use of 'but [something]'. There was a big debate here only! I had asked that months back.

Comment: @MaulikV Is it always the case for you that when you see "anything but X", X must be either positive or negative?

Comment: In a sentence yes, as I had asked a question (don't remember the link) - I can withstand anything but heat. I always wondered then is it 'including' or 'excluding'. Then looking at answers and comments, I started learning about the format 'anything but'. Anyway, source included and if you (and others) want, I delete this answer. The purpose is solved, the OP now knows about it. I'll feel happy *personally*! :) @DamkerngT.